# Missing parenthesis in expression in Oracle Documentation?

Tags: oracle

Found this condition in Oracle SQL documentation:

```
NVL(salary, 0) + NVL(salary + (salary*commission_pct, 0) > 25000)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/About-SQL-Conditions.htm#SQLRF52101

It explains, "The following complex condition adds the salary value to the commission_pct value (substituting the value 0 for null) and determines whether the sum is greater than the number constant 25000:". 
But when I tried to execute it, it throws an error,

> 'MISSING RIGHT PARENTHESIS'.

Is this condition valid ? or Is there some other way to execute it.

```
SELECT  NVL(salary, 0) + NVL(salary + (salary*commission_pct, 0) > 25000) FROM HR.Employees;
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Regardless of whether the condition is correct or not, in your sample code you `SELECT` a condition, which makes no sense. Perhaps it would if Oracle had the Boolean data type - you would expect a "condition" to be an expression of that data type - but Oracle does not implement Boolean.

Comment: Could you edit the title to be more informative about the problem you are trying to solve? This will be more helpful to other members in the community.

Comment: That's a great discovery. You try to claim for some reward from Oracle for finding this error in documentation.

Comment: @KaushikNayak - I've already left feedback on the relevant doc, referring back to this question *8-)

Answer (score 1):

The condition is intended to be used in a `WHERE` clause, not a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM HR.Employees
WHERE NVL(salary, 0) + NVL(salary + salary*commission_pct, 0) > 25000 ;
```

(This also adjusts the parentheses.)

Adding the salary twice doesn't make sense.  Presumably the intended logic is:

```
WHERE NVL(salary, 0) + NVL(salary*commission_pct, 0) > 25000 ;
```

However, I would write this as:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM HR.Employees
WHERE COALESCE(salary, 0) * (1 + COALESCE(commission_pct, 0)) > 25000 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a documentation bug; even in the [12cR2 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/About-SQL-Conditions.htm) it still says:

```
NVL(salary, 0) + NVL(salary + (salary*commission_pct, 0) > 25000)
```

instead of

```
NVL(salary, 0) + NVL(salary*commission_pct, 0) > 25000
```

or

```
NVL(salary + salary*commission_pct, 0) > 25000
```

or (closer to the original, though this looks like an odd thing to want to find)

```
NVL(salary, 0) + NVL(salary + salary*commission_pct, 0) > 25000
```

or some other valid variant depending on what it's supposed to be checking...

And as others have already pointed out it's a *condition*, so it goes in a `where` clause, not in the select list.

Comment: The guy who wrote the documentation probably meant `NVL(salary + salary*commission_pct, 0)` but didn't know how to get it right. The way he wrote it, salary is added twice - inconsistent with the plain English translation.

Comment: I think it's just a mistake creating or editing the statement, yes, absolutely.

Comment: ...or perhaps, as Gordon suggests (using different code): `nvl(salary + salary * nvl(commission, 0), 0)` - so if the salary is not NULL but the commission is NULL, the commission is treated as 0 and the salary is returned unaffected. Although, with some more thought... if we compare by > 25000, then the outer NVL shouldn't be needed. (Now I am asking too much of documentation writers though!)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. It is a documentation  bug as at the time of writing this answer.

You should use this condition in where clause rather than select, removing some of the braces.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    hr.employees
WHERE
    nvl(salary,0) + nvl(salary + salary * commission_pct,0) > 25000;
```

However, this is a more appropriate logic to compare.

```
NVL(salary, 0) + NVL(salary*commission_pct, 0) > 25000
```

Comment: You've skipped over the changes you made to the parentheses; it's not *just* that it needs to be in the where clause?